# prolog "triggers" on persistent predicates i.e. run some code when something changes

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm using library(persistency), and I would like to run some triggers when the underlying database changes.

This is some example code:

```
:- use_module(library(persistency)).
:- persistent temperature(t:any).
:- persistent running(device:any).
:- db_attach('foo.db', []), db_sync(gc(0)).

run_triggers :- forall(trigger(GoalCond, Body), ignore((GoalCond, Body))).

trigger(
    (temperature(T), T > 23, \+ running(cooler)),
    (writeln('temperature too high, activating cooler'), assert_running(cooler))
).
trigger(
    (temperature(T), T < 4, running(cooler)),
    (writeln('temperature too low, deactivating cooler'), retractall_running(cooler))
).
```

and this is me running it:

```
?- run_triggers.
true.

?- temperature(T).
T = -2.

?- retractall_temperature(_), assert_temperature(25).
true.

?- run_triggers.
temperature too high, activating cooler
true.

?- running(X).
X = cooler.
```

Ideally, I would like to run `run_triggers` **automatically** after each change in the DB.
How to do it?

In this simple example I have only two persistent predicates, but in the real case I have hundreds of those, so wrapping those manually is not an option.

Comment: I would make a different predicate that wraps `assert_temperature` that calls `run_triggers` after calling it. Then, don't export `assert_temperature` at all, export your new wrapper instead.

Comment: @DanielLyons the problem is that the persistent predicates I have to wrap are hundreds, so it's not that simple

Comment: Logalk's event-driven programming support (https://logtalk.org/manuals/userman/events.html) would be a perfect fit but it would require doing persistency differently.

Comment: Maybe find a way to wrap the `persistent` declaration instead, so that it does some book-keeping for the triggers at the same time?

Comment: The persistancy library is implemented in a few lines of code. Maybe you can just modify it a bit (for example adding a goal after `persistency:DBAction` in the asserted procedures; look at `assert_clause/3` from persistance.pl)